# CSS and images from a different folder are not read when rendering template using Golang

Tags: html, css, go

I am trying to render a template using the html/template module of Golang. But only CSS files and images from the same folder as the page i am rendering are executed, those located in a different folder are ignored. Here is my code:

```
func render(w http.ResponseWriter, filename string, data interface{}) {
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(filename)
    if err != nil {
      http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    if err := tmpl.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
      http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
  }
```

For this page for example:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Start Connect</title>
  <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="one-page.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

The one-page.css is executed but not the bootstrap.

Comment: Is the path correct relative to the **URL** that this page is loaded from? Remember, the browser is handling the relative path and using it to construct a new URL to request the resource from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Using `../css` on the web should be avoided and likely is your error source. Your go server likely cannot resolve the file (because you don't have a handler for the `../css` URI).
So you should change the `../css` part to `/css` and tell your server (you didn't provide details, so I cannot show you code) to handle `/css` URIs by serving the files.

Assuming that you are using the default `net/http` mux, your code should look something like:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))))
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
```